# Update wallet to multi tokens

Tags: wallet

I don't know if here, I have to ask, but if not, please direct me.
How can I make a wallet accept more coins.
More exactly: I have a wallet BEP2, native currecncies is BNB (Binance). What needs to be done for this wallet to accept other BEP2 tokens.
I didn't try anything because I don't know where to start.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you buy a hardware wallet, such as ledger or trezor.
Those wallets are compatible with a wide range of cryptocurrencies. If they do not provide support to a coin, that coin is not worth buying.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. My problem is: money is already in this wallet, but it is not supported for that token. equivalent 7000 usd

Comment: Do you have the wallet private key? or the seed (12 words?)
In Ethereum blockchain you can add any token manually using token contract address, I don't know how binance chain works, but probably the same way.

I just google about it and found guard wallet. I don't know that wallet, but you have few options because you are using a not common blockchain

https://guarda.com/blog/bep-2-wallet/